# Trouble with PHPUnit on Zend Server CE - MacOSX

Tags: macos, unit-testing, phpunit, zend-server-ce

I've installed Zend Server CE on my MacOS Lion, and everything is running smooth except from PHPUnit.

My installation of PHPUnit was made from the PERL that comes with Zend Server CE.

Here is the output from when I run phpunit through the console:

```
Failed loading ”/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xdebug.so”:      dlopen(”/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xdebug.so”, 9): image not found
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library     '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mcrypt.so' -     dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mcrypt.so, 9): Library not loaded:     /usr/lib/libltdl.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mcrypt.so
  Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance() in     /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 39
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
```

Does anybody know what the problem or problems could be?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I assume you mean `pear` not perl? :) - Apart from that: Yeah the install seems pretty broken but OSX+ZendServer is so far of the beaten track (both things can be enough trouble on their own when it comes to php(+pear) imho) that i don't have a clue there. Sorry :)

Comment: I'll add this in a comment instead of an answer because I'm not sure but I would say this looks like an environment problem.  It would seem that PHP Unit is either passing an incorrect environment (meaning your PHP interpreter can't find all it's configs and files) or it was compiled against the wrong binaries.

Comment: Yeah, and what makes me sad even more is the fact that those errors appeared after a clean installation of Zend Server CE along with PHPUnit installation through pear. OBS: Yeah, i meant pear. Does anybody have any idea on how to fix or install those two the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this is my first answer. So go easy on me.

Tonight I had the very same issues with Zend Server CE on OSX Lion.  In order to solve them, you'll have to install xcode as the **unix development tools** are required.

Let's get started, you have two issues: *xdebug.so* and *libltdl.3.dylib*

**First** *xdebug.so* is not found, to install it you should run the following from the command line:

```
sudo su -
```

It will ask you for you password (if you don't have one just press the enter key). Then:

```
export CFLAGS="-arch i386 $CFLAGS"
export CCFLAGS="-arch i386 $CCFLAGS"
export CXXFLAGS="-arch i386 $CXXFLAGS"
export LDFLAGS="-arch i386 $LDFLAGS"
/usr/local/zend/bin/pear config-set php_ini /usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini
/usr/local/zend/bin/pecl install xdebug
```

The first four lines, force the compiler to generate a 32 bit binary, as Zend Server is a 32 bit binary and OSX Lion is a 64 bit operating system.

Alright, now you should have *xdebug.so* installed on */usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions*, just make sure that your */usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini* file loads xdebug with the following line after all other extensions and before the *[zend]* section:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xdebug.so
```

Here's the fragment from my *php.ini*:

```
...
;extension=odbc.so
;extension=imagick.so
zend_extension=/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xdebug.so

[zend]
zend_extension=/usr/local/zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so
...
```

If it doesn't please add it manually, then check if your *php.ini* file contains the following line and delete it as xdebug must me loaded as a Zend extension.

```
extension=xdebug.so
```

**Second**, as soon as you install xcode, *libltdl.dylib* will be available in */usr/lib*, so you can create a symbolic link to it with the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libltdl.dylib /usr/lib/libltdl.3.dylib
```

Next time you run phpunit everything should go smoothly (haven't tested any mcrypt functions though).

Comment: I made a fresh installation of Zend Server CE and followed your steps strictly, but I can't solve the issue. The case is, at the point I need to manually add the xdebug as a zend extension into the php.ini file, when I restart my Zend Server, the extension manager says that the extension could not be loaded due to an error. And the worst part is the error doesn't show up.

Any other ideas?

How is your fresh install?

Comment: Ok, I got it working. But only when I am at /usr/local/zend/bin folder and run it like this: ./phpunit --version. If I run the phpunit command from any other path, it results me in this error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance() in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 39
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0

Comment: Maybe you can try adding /usr/local/zend/bin to your default path with the following command: "export PATH=/usr/local/zend/bin:$PATH" and try to run phpunit from anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the problem with the mcrypt, when I tried to start the phpunit.

The warning does not appear, if you run phpunit with sudo :)

> sudo ./phpunit --version
>
> PHPUnit 3.6.6 by Sebastian Bergmann.